# Alignment of options in \question environment

Tags: exam

I am using `\question` environment to make a Objective type question paper. I am using the following code:

```
\question Which compound would give 5-keto-2-methyl hexanal upon ozonolysis ?

\begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice \begin{minipage}[c]{8em} \vspace{0pt} \chemfig{[:18]*5(--(-[:30]CH_3)=(-[:90]CH_3)--)} \end{minipage}
    \choice \begin{minipage}[c]{8em} \vspace{0pt} \chemfig{[:18]*5(-(-[:-30]CH_3)-=(-[:90]CH_3)--)} \end{minipage}
    \choice \begin{minipage}[c]{8em} \vspace{0pt} \chemfig{[:18]*5((-[:210]CH_3)--=(-[:90]CH_3)--)} \end{minipage}
    \choice \begin{minipage}[c]{8em} \vspace{0pt} \chemfig{[:18]*5(--=(-[:90]CH_3)-(-[:150,0.9])-)} \end{minipage}
\end{oneparchoices}
```

Issue is how do i make the options aligned into two sections like option A and B in one line and option C and D in another line(exactly below the option A & B)

Should I use oneparchoices or should i use something else to rectify the problem?

I want options to be like :

> Que...
>   A.)                          B.)
>   C.)                          D.)

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Which compound would give 5-keto-2-methyl hexanal upon ozonolysis ?
\begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    \choice AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    \choice AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    \choice AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
\end{oneparchoices}\end{questions}

\end{document}

Comment: The options in above codes would come AAAAAAAA , BBBBBBBB, CCCCCCC and so on are not alinged.

I want them to be exactly how Que. papers have it: Alinged as asked above:

Que :  Which compound would give 5-keto-2-methyl hexanal upon ozonolysis ? 
A.) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA        B.) BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
C.) CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC                 D.) DDDDDDD

Comment: You can edit your question and add your MWE to the question. Click on EDIT below your question.